# OffsetDateTime returns the datetime in wrong format

Tags: spring, datetime, jackson

I use a Spring 4.3.4, a Jackson 2.8.6 and a Tomcat 8.5.11. I've some REST API:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/netadvice")
public class NetworkAdviceController {

    ...

    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/offsetDateTime", 
            method = RequestMethod.GET, 
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public OffsetDateTime todayOffsetDateTime() {
        return OffsetDateTime.now();
    }
}
```

After call `/netadvice/offsetDateTime` I would like to receive the datetime in the following format: `2017-02-14T08:46:06.102Z` but I receive something like this: `1487062454.957000000`.

**What did I wrong and how can I fix this issue?**

The following code is my custom datetime serializer and deserializer:

```
@Configuration
public class JsonConfig {

    public static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
        javaTimeModule.addSerializer(OffsetDateTime.class, new OffsetDateTimeSerializer());
        javaTimeModule.addDeserializer(OffsetDateTime.class, new OffsetdateTimeDeserializer());
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);      
        objectMapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule);    
        return objectMapper;
    }

    public class OffsetDateTimeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<OffsetDateTime> {
        @Override
        public void serialize(OffsetDateTime value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
                throws IOException {

            gen.writeString(value.format(FORMATTER));
        }
    }

    public class OffsetdateTimeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<OffsetDateTime> {
        @Override
        public OffsetDateTime deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {

            return OffsetDateTime.parse(p.getValueAsString(), FORMATTER);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With the `JavaTimeModule` you don't need the custom serializer and deserializer. Just remove them.

Comment: I've just removed the custom serializer and deserializer but unfortunately it doesn't work as well.

Comment: I've just noticed that if I use a Spring Boot, my code works.

Comment: I have the same issue here... waiting for a solution